# How to keep up with the gas price in a backend service

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

I have a small nodesjs app that is writing to a contract every now and then.

It works, but i had to manually check the current gas price and deploy afterwards.

What can I do to automate that? I dont want to hardcode the gasprice but set one dynamically that gets my TX through (in average) in one hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using geth and you do not specify the gas prices parameter geth will set it automatically to the current standard price using information from the previous blocks.

If you need the value of the gas price that your node is using do: `web3.eth.gasPrice` and it will return the current gas price.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm running with infura service (i think they use in turn geth). However, `web3.eth.gasPrice` is undefined. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas does work though :-)

Comment: the link you provided estimate the gas used, not the gas price.